# Bluetooth Printer is not working in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-7.1

```
string command = "Welcome To Solutions....                                                                                                                            ";
        Byte[] buffer = new byte[command.Length];
        StreamSocket socket = null;
        buffer = StringToAscii(command);
        PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
        var pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
        if (pairedDevices.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("No paired devices were found.");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                PeerInformation selectedDevice = pairedDevices[0];
                socket = new StreamSocket();
                await socket.ConnectAsync(selectedDevice.HostName, "1");
                await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.AsBuffer(buffer));
                socket.Dispose();
                Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

This Code Working Fine When i Debug the code. But When i Run the code without Debugging Action cannot performed. when i      debuig this code it's Working fine.  what wrong with me.

![Printind demo][10![]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKzAn.jpg)

Comment: Why The Uppercase Words?

Comment: not understand what u say

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what printer are you using but you need to specify some commands. For Zebra printers your code looks something like this:

```
string command = "^XA^LH30,30^F020,10^AD^FDWelcome To Solutions...^FS^XZ";
Byte[] buffer = new byte[command.Length];
StreamSocket socket = null;
buffer = StringToAscii(command);
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
var pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();
if (pairedDevices.Count == 0)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("No paired devices were found.");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        PeerInformation selectedDevice = pairedDevices[0];
        socket = new StreamSocket();
        await socket.ConnectAsync(selectedDevice.HostName, "1");
        await socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions.AsBuffer(buffer));
        socket.Dispose();
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    catch{ }
}
```

Verify that your Release mode allows code optimization.

Comment: sounds very strange... May you have problems with the device searching. Move your try..catch to your whole code in order to find an error. In your catch put a Popup message. Let me know.

Comment: Some times print ok but some time it' print "ok" "ok" "error1" and some times none print